# Clang doesn't evaluate the value of the constexpr function for the non-constexpr variable at compile time

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr

Some code:

```cpp
constexpr int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int a = sum(4, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile this code with `clang-9` but it doesn't evaluate the value of `int a` in main function at compile time. 
If i use `constexpr int a` clang evaluates it at compile time but i can't change this variable at runtime.

But `gcc-7.1` evaluate the value of `int a` at compile time.

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`constexpr` specifier only means that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function at compile time. It does not mean that it should be evaluated at compile time. So different compilers/versions have flexibility in this matter.

If you want to enforce such evaluation at compile time, then the variable it is assigned to should also be `constexpr`.

This happens when `a` is `constexpr int` and not just a plain `int`.

To fix your particular issue, you should use an intermediate variable which is `constexpr` and then assign its value to a variable that can be changed.

Comment: Does GCC trust the developer more? What is the reason that clang limits this?

Comment: Don't think it is a GCC vs. Clang issue. Even older versions of GCC do not do this. Difficult to speculate on the motivations of compiler writers when making such decisions.

Comment: @DarkHell Let's look at [what clang actually produces](https://godbolt.org/z/lmvYff). You can see that in debug mode with `-g`, `sum` is indeed not evaluated at compile time. This allows a debugger to step into `sum` so you have a reasonable chance to debug. When you enable optimizations with `-O2` it evaluates everything at compile time. So clang lets you chose between debuggability and performance. If you need both then consider using `-Og` which does optimizations that don't inhibit debuggability.

Answer (score 6):

When you want a value to be precomputed at compile time but then bound to an identifier which allows for modification, you can only force this by initializing a non-`constexpr` object with a `constexpr` object:

```
constexpr int init = sum(4, 5);
int a = init;
```